# rails コマンドのインストール方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`gem 'rails'`
をかいて `bundle install` したんですが `rails` コマンドが見つかりません

---

rbenv, ruby をインストールした後

Gemfile に

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
```

とかいて 
`bundle install`
を実行し、依存関係のあるジェムがいろいろインストールされた後

```
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 43 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from i18n:

HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
But that may break your application.

Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.

For more info see:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
```

とでてインストールに成功したようなのですが
rails コマンドを実行しようとしてもコマンドが見つかりません

rbenv は $HOME/.rbenv にインストール

.bashrc に

```
# rbenv
export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="$PATH:$RBENV_ROOT/bin"
  if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
    eval "$(rbenv init -)";
  fi
fi
```

をかいて source 済み

which ruby, gem, bundle は全部 $HOME/.rbenv/shims/ 以下になってます
rails コマンドはどこにインストールされたんでしょうか

OS は
5.0.0-37-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 00:14:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ruby は 2.6.5 です

## 追記

なぜか ubuntu 上で gem install rails だけでは rails がインストールできません

```
ubuntu> gem install rails
Fetching rails-6.0.2.1.gem
Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.1
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.1
Installing ri documentation for rails-6.0.2.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
ubuntu> rails -v

Command 'rails' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rbenvを使用している場合、`gem install`でインストールしたgemのコマンドを使用したい場合は`rbenv rehash`を実行する必要があります。

Comment: それでした！　できました！

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'railties'
```

で .rbenv/shims/rails に入りました

Answer (score 1):

システム全体で rails を使いたいのであれば、まず `gem install` します。

```sh
gem install rails
rails -v
```

そうではなくてプロジェクト単位のディレクトリに rails を入れて bundler 経由で動かしたいのであれば、`bundle install` 後に `bundle exec` を使えば良いです。

```sh
bundle install  # 必要に応じて --path を指定する
bundle exec rails -v
```

Comment: gem install と Gemfile にかいて bundle install するのとではインストールされる場所が違うということですか？

Comment: それは `--path` を指定するかどうかによります。